Flagging a Staging Ground question as spam should close-vote it too
I ran across an obvious piece of spam in Staging Ground.  I flagged it accordingly, but I still had the set of choices in the "Review Question" box.  It clearly shouldn't be promoted to a "real" question, but I also don't want to spend lots of time in the UI just filtering this out.
(I ultimately picked "vote as off-topic", "...because it's spam".)
Should a spam flag automatically count as a close vote for Staging Ground purposes?  Should there be some sort of streamlined workflow for helping reviewers to get these out of the system quickly?

I don't see much of a reason to treat it in any other way than posts on the public site: Just flag it and move on/skip.

It should be treated differently in this if a user does promote flagged spam out of SG they should receive a SG review suspension. We don’t need users promoting spam and not being told they made an error.

@SecurityHound Yeah, following the post and using a custom flag (regarding the reviewer) if necessary is an option as well. But I guess mods (and/or Charcoal) is too fast for that to happen in most cases.

@dan1st - An automatic flag should be raised for every question that comes out of SG that ends up then being flagged as spam. This was a moderator can confirm, not only was the question always spam, they can suspend any user from the SG promoting process for a period of time. Since not identifying spam is a big deal. You’re welcome to ignore or skip the SG item but if you improperly handle spam you should get a timeout from the review process

I think this wouldn't be as important as the spam flag would be a red flag in the mod dashboard even when the post is published (I think) (published posts cannot be spam-flagged in the SG so it wouldn'tresult in a deleted SG post while the main one is still there I guess). And as the SG question is normally not deleted right after publishing (Roomba can be neglected), the mods would see it being published. Also if SmokeDetector found the SG post, it probably also notices the one on the main site. Hence I don't think it's that much of a concern.
